# auto and {}-lists question regarding Stroustrup C++ book

Tags: c++, c++11

The following appears in Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed. Page 164.

```
T v3 = f();
T v3 {f()}; // works if and only if the type of f() can be implicitly converted to a T

auto v3 = f(); // v3 is of some appropriate type
```

Does anyone have an example of what type `T` could be for these examples?

My understanding of assigning functions to a variable are as follows:

```
void (*fptr)(void) = &f;
```

Unfortunately this is not in the form of RHS `f()`.  So I'm a bit confused here on use cases of the above examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not assign a function pointer here.  `f()` means call the `()` operator of whatever `f` is and return the result.  So if we say `f` is

```
int f() { return 42; }
```

then for

```
T v3 = f();
```

`T` needs to be something that can be created from an `int`. With

```
T v3 {f()};
```

`T` needs to be something that can be created from an `int`, and it also cannot be a narrowing conversion.  With

```
auto v3 = f();
```

`v3` will have a type that follows the template argument deuction rules, so `int` in this case.  If `f` were to return a `int&`, it would still be an `int` though since the deduction rules don't create a reference.

Comment: It might also be worth noting that in `T v3 = f();`, if `T` is a used-defined type, `T`'s constructor from `int` should not be marked as `explicit`.

Answer (score 0):

The assignments involving `f()` are dealing with the return value of `f()` and not the function `f` as a value.  So, `T` can be an `int` when the return type of `f` is `char`.